# Get Word Permutations

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to write a function to get all of the permutations of the array elements.

I do not want you to write the function for me! I want to work through it myself. Please do me the favor of letting me work through it.

**Input**: `[1,2,3]`
**Output**: `123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.`

I believe the output should be an array of length factorial(input.length). So if the input is a three element array, the output should contain 3*2 elements. A four element input array would result in an array length of 24 (4*3*2) elements, with each element of the input array being the first element of a six element array.

**Input**: ['a','bo']
**Output**: ['abo', 'boa']

**Input**: `[1,2,3,4]`
**Output**:

```
[
1234 1243 1324 1342 1423 1432
2134 2143 2314 2341 2413 2431
3124 3142 3214 3241 3412 3421
4123 4132 4213 4231 4312 4321
]
```

(commas omitted from the output pseudocode).

Here is what I have so far. It isn't working. I think I need a nested loop.

```
function getWordPermutations(words) {
    const len = words.length;
    const factorial = n => !(n > 1) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
    let r = [words.join("")];

    for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        let tmp = words[i];
        let nextIndex = words[i+1] ? i+1 : words.length-1 - i;
        words[i] = words[nextIndex];
        words[nextIndex] = tmp;
        r.push(words.join(""))
    }
    console.log(r);
    return r;
}

getWordPermutations([1,2,3]); // Result: ["123", "213", "231", "132"]
```

It doesn't complete all of the permutations. Can you ask me some questions to get me to think about it.

Comment: You should expect your result to have n! elements in it, but you only push to the result (n+1) times. You should think of a way to do this with either recursion or a nested loop.

Comment: If you need permutations of 2 elements, you swap them. For permutation of 3 elements, you take each element of the word, and append the permutation of the rest of the 2 elements. For permutation of n elements, you need to find the permutation of  n - 1 elements first. That's one way to think about the problem.

Comment: I cannot reply directly to Kevin's comment. Comments are flattened. ¶ ,                                                              ¶, I understand swapping the last two elements, then the last two the the third from the last? I am not smart enough to do it in code. I am stuck. ¶ ,                                                              ¶, I also didn't consider same value elements, as ['a','a','a'] // one

Comment: I have just finished watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYFd7VHKyWQ . I will have to watch it at least one more time. There is code on his Github and he seems to explain it thoroughly, though I haven't gotten it yet. I'm not smart like I used to be...

Comment: Kevin was talking about a recursive solution and the video Garrett posted also uses recursion (in Java). I agree this is the way to go. I'll try to write a Javascript implementation if I find the time.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from, https://github.com/mission-peace/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/recursion/StringPermutation.java

and re-implemented in Javascript.

```js
function permute(input) {
  let countMap = new Map();
  for (ch of input.split("")) {
    //console.log(ch, countMap.has(ch));
    if (countMap.has(ch)) {
      let inc = countMap.get(ch) + 1;
      countMap.set(ch, inc);
    } else {
      countMap.set(ch, 1);
    }
  }
  //console.log(countMap);
  str = new Array(countMap.size); //char[countMap.size()];
  count = new Array(countMap.size); //int[countMap.size];
  index = 0;
  for (let [key, val] of countMap.entries()) {
    //console.log(key, val);
    str[index] = key;
    count[index] = val;
    index++;
  }
  //console.log(str, count);
  resultList = new Array();
  result = new Array(input.length); //char[input.length]
  permuteUtil(str, count, result, 0, resultList);
  return resultList;
}

function permuteUtil(str, count, result, level, resultList) {
  if (level == result.length) {
    resultList.push(result.join("")); //resultList.add(new String(result));
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (count[i] == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    result[level] = str[i];
    count[i]--;
    permuteUtil(str, count, result, level + 1, resultList);
    count[i]++;
  }
}

permute("AABC").forEach((s) => console.log(s));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The output is as expected:

```
AABC
AACB
ABAC
ABCA
ACAB
ACBA
BAAC
BACA
BCAA
CAAB
CABA
CBAA
```

**If you want a dynamic input and output via HTML and to allow more than just single characters then (https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/abOMpgz)**:

For your specific examples, we just need to enter a comma-separated list like "1,2,3" into the HTML input tag:

```js
function permute(input) {
  let countMap = new Map();
  const input_arr = input.split(",");
  for (ch of input_arr) {
    //console.log(ch, countMap.has(ch));
    if (countMap.has(ch)) {
      let inc = countMap.get(ch) + 1;
      countMap.set(ch, inc);
    } else {
      countMap.set(ch, 1);
    }
  }
  //console.log(countMap);
  str = new Array(countMap.size); //char[countMap.size()];
  count = new Array(countMap.size); //int[countMap.size];
  index = 0;
  for (let [key, val] of countMap.entries()) {
    //console.log(key, val);
    str[index] = key;
    count[index] = val;
    index++;
  }
  //console.log(str, count);
  resultList = new Array();
  result = new Array(input_arr.length); //char[input.length]
  permuteUtil(str, count, result, 0, resultList);
  return resultList;
}

function permuteUtil(str, count, result, level, resultList) {
  if (level == result.length) {
    resultList.push(result.join(',')); //resultList.add(new String(result));
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (count[i] == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    result[level] = str[i];
    count[i]--;
    permuteUtil(str, count, result, level + 1, resultList);
    count[i]++;
  }
}

//permute("1,2,3").forEach((s) => console.log(s));
const output_tag = document.getElementById("output");
const input_tag = document.getElementById("input");
const go = document.getElementById("go");
go.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  output_tag.innerText = permute(String(input_tag.value)).join("\n");
});
output_tag.innerText = permute(String(input_tag.value)).join("\n");
```

```html
<h3>Input (comma separated):</h3>
<input id="input" value="1,2,3">
<br /><br />
<button id="go">Go</button>
<br>
<h3>Output:</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.